# How do I click an anchor element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, onclick, anchor

using jQuery :

I want to take the user to www.someurl.com whenever they click on a specific `<div>`

I cannot place a `<a>` on top of that `<div>`

I want the link to open in a new tab (if the user's using tabs obviously) and not in a new window.

I'm currently trying this "hack" :

```
$("#the-div-in-question").click(function ()
{
   $("<a href='www.someurl.com' target='_blank'/>").appendTo("body").css(
   {
     position: 'absolute',  
     top: 1,
     left: 1,
     height: 1,
     width: 1
   }).click();
});
```

But it's not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: why don't you try window.location("your URL") in the onClick event of div

Comment: As I said in my original post, I want the link to open in a new tab.

Comment: check the new code ...!!

Comment: Why can't you just wrap the `div` with an `a` element?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead...

```
$("#the-div-in-question").click(function () {
    window.open("http://www.someurl.com", "_blank");
});
```

You don't need an anchor - you can just open the page in a new window or tab using javascript.

Whether it opens in a new window or tab is entirely up to the end user's browser settings and cannot be overridden.

Comment: As I noted in my original post, I want the link to open in a new tab.

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  I've changed it now :)

Comment: Note that `window.open` will not be allowed when it is called from some kind of user-driven event handler.

Comment: As I noted in my original post, I want the link to open in a new tab. Not in a new window.

Comment: @TheRandomGuy You can't do that.  It's entirely up to the end user's browser settings and cannot be overridden.

Comment: As I noted in my original post, if the user is using tabs then I can do that. Clicking on anchor elements using target=_blank in that case, always opens up new tabs. Using window.open, even if the user's using tabs, is first treated as a popUp which is blocked if the user is using a popUp blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/v9kRN/

```
$("#the-div-in-question").click(function () {
    $('<a href="http://url.com" target="_blank"></a>').appendTo($(this));
    $(this).find('a')[0].click();
});
```

Another Trick by wrapping the div by a tag

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/v9kRN/1/

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#the-div-in-question").wrap(function() {
        return '<a href="https://google.com" id="link" target="_blank" />';
     });
});
```

## **CSS**

```
#link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: check the demo it opens in new tab

Comment: This is not working. It's opening up a window which is being blocked as a popup window.Anchor elements using target=_blank are not treated as pop-ups.